# Crystal Report load failed issue

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, windows-services

I have created windows service to generate crystal reports. Also, I have installed it in the client machine. If the user is given the windows service as a manual start,  its working fine. If the user is given the windows service as a autostart, it is not working. Shown the message like Load Report Failed. As per my assumption, some of the dependencies are not loaded when the user set as an autostart. But I don't know which dependencies are missed. Let me know any dependencies or services needed when we set the window service as autostart.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know the precise dependencies, try setting the service's Startup type to **Automatic (Delayed Start)**:

[image]

With this setting, Windows will launch your service a couple of minutes after boot — when all critical services should be up and ready.

[Read about the "Automatic (Delayed Start)" setting here](https://superuser.com/a/285655/54909).

Comment: But I have installed the same things to other clients also. It's working fine. Only one client has the problem. I have checked the configuration, all system configurations are same.

Comment: No doubt there is a problem with that installation. The answer does not attempt to diagnose that problem; it simply focuses on a practical way to move past it.